# Shuffle data in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, notepad++, sqlite-net

I have a data like

```
id1,apple,0
id2,orange,0
id3,banana,0
id4,carrot,0
ida,kiwi,1
idb,potato,1
idc,cakes,1
idd,chocos,1
```

I need to shuffle on the base of last column (0 THEN 1) like

```
id1,apple,0
ida,kiwi,1
id2,orange,0
idb,potato,1
id3,banana,0
idc,cakes,1
id4,carrot,0
idd,chocos,1
```

Is that possible in sqlite or in notepad++ ??

Comment: Are you expecting alternate 0 and 1's or are you wanting random rows?

Comment: Alternative 0 and 1's...actually i have 2 data sets.. first end with 0 and second with 1 and i have to merge them and then shuffle... it best shuffles when there will be alternative 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

If the version of SQLite you use supports it you can do it with [`row_number()`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/) window function:

```
select t.id, t.fruit, t.number 
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by number order by id) rn 
  from tablename
) t
order by t.rn
```

If you need the rows shuffled, replace `order by id` with `order by random()`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tUgomLG3jvXjmv6qNic5XF/0).
If you can't use window functions:

```
select t.id, t.fruit, t.number 
from (
  select t.*,
    (select count(*) from tablename where number = t.number and id < t.id) rn
  from tablename t
) t
order by t.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tUgomLG3jvXjmv6qNic5XF/1).
Results:

```
| id  | fruit  | number |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| id1 | apple  | 0      |
| ida | kiwi   | 1      |
| id2 | orange | 0      |
| idb | potato | 1      |
| id3 | banana | 0      |
| idc | cakes  | 1      |
| id4 | carrot | 0      |
| idd | chocos | 1      |
```

Comment: The second solution works....but its not exactly alternative 0 and 1...

Comment: As you can see in the demo it works for the sample data you posted. If your actual data is different I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `row_number()` in the `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col1),
         col1;
```

Often "shuffle" implies randomness ("interleaving" would not).  If that is what you mean:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by col3 order by random()),
         col1
```